# I got a error like this Column count doesn't match value count at row. 1 please solve this error

Tags: php, mysql

//this my query

```
if(isset($_POST["break-first"])) {
    $bflag='true';
    $bfid=$_POST["break-first"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM food_details WHERE food_id = '$bfid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($_SESSION["connect"],$query);
        if(!$result) {
            $error = mysqli_error($_SESSION["connect"]);
            print $error;
            exit;
        }

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $bfid =$row["food_id"];
        $bf=$row["f_name"];
        $bprice= $row["price"];
    }
```

and i got this error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

[image]

Comment: Have you debug your code ? by printing '$query' and '$result' ??

Comment: What! Why you have stored your connection variable in `session`?

Comment: @Mohamed Haseem check the answers and mark and up-vote the answer which is correct and more descriptive to you. thanks.

Comment: Peoples are not interested in getting answers and telling final position. I am deleting my  answer

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM food_details WHERE food_id = '$bfid'";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT food_id,f_name,price FROM food_details WHERE food_id = '$bfid'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "database_id", "database_password", "database_name");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT food_id,f_name,price FROM food_details WHERE food_id = ?");

$query->bind_param('s',$bfid);

if (!$query->execute()){
    echo $mysqli->error;
}

$query->bind_result($food_id,$f_name,$price);

$query->store_result();
$query->fetch();
```

Note1 : Prepared statements are more secure.

Note2 : You can replace 's' with 'i' if bfid is integer.

Comment: I have added database connectivity code as well. As I guess he is storing it in session variable. Which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> mysqli_fetch_array() function fetches a result row as an associative array

```
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $bfid =$row["food_id"];
    $bf=$row["f_name"];
    $bprice= $row["price"];
```